# Proving that $\Omega$ is bounded.

Tags: general-topology

$\Omega$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that every sequence of $\Omega$ has a subsequence which converges to some point in $\Omega$. I need to prove that $\Omega$ is compact( a set $S$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded). I have managed to prove that $\Omega$ is closed. *But I am unable to prove that $\Omega$ is bounded and I will appreciate a hint in that direction*.

(All I could come up was that if $\Omega$ is not bounded, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $\displaystyle z_n \in \Omega$ such that $|z_{n}|\ge n$. That means there is a subsequence $\{z_{n_k}\}$ such that $z_{n_k}$ converges to some $w\in \Omega$, so $|z_{n_k}|$ converges to $|w|$ which means that $\{z_{n_k}\}$ is bounded. I was thinking along the lines of looking at terms of the sequence other than the subsequence and producing another convergent subsequence but this is vague and incorrect.  )

Thanks!

Comment: You're going in the right direction. Assume an unbounded sequence with $|z_k| > |z_n| + \epsilon$ for all $k>n$. You can then prove that no subsequence of $(z_k)$ can converge.

Comment: Note that $|z_{n_k}|\geq n_k\geq n$. Since the index of the $n$-th term of a subsequence is always $\geq n$ (Otherwise, the indexes wouldn't be strictly increasing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have become a bit distracted by the unnecessary framing of the proof as a proof by contradiction. Do it by contraposition. Assume $\Omega$ is unbounded. Now you have to exhibit a sequence of $\Omega$ with no convergent subsequence. Let $|x_n|\to\infty$. Consider an arbitrary subsequence $x_{n_k}$. What can you say about $|x_{n_k}|$? Conclude that $x_{n_k}$ cannot possible be convergent.

What you'd started doing is essentially the above, but you retained the assumption that $x_n$ had a convergent subsequence for the sake of a contradiction. A finished version of your proof would more or less amount to the above with an extra "...but $x_n$ was assumed the have a convergent subsequence, which is a contradiction" at the end.